# Right settings of vsftpd?

Tags: ftp, settings, vsftpd

I installed vsftpd on Linux Mint, I changed some settings to the configuration file so it permits anonymous users, however I want to redirect them to a certain directory where they can upload files. I'm just confused among the settings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure the following setting is configured in your /etc/vsftpd.conf file

```
   anon_root=/example/directory/ # Directory to be used for an anonymous login
```

if you are trying to create a soft link to redirect to certain directory then note that a soft links cannot resolve unless where they link to is inside the chroot area.